# How to let users define custom notification conditions?

Tags: javascript, datatables, user-defined-functions, dsl, usability

I'm developing a web app featuring a data table updated in real-time, e.g.:

```
+-------+--------+--------+-----+
| Event | Value1 | Value2 | ... |
+-------+--------+--------+-----+
| A     | 132.43 |   9431 | ... |
| B     |   0.00 | -34.00 | ... |
| C     |   0.32 |  12.00 | ... |
+-------+--------+--------+-----+
```

Users should be able to receive a notification when certain data patterns occur.

What is a good way to allow users to specify user-defined strategies for when they want to receive notifications about a specific event?

e.g.:

```
Strategy 1:
Notify when Value1 == 0

Strategy 2: 
Notify when Value1 < 0 or Value2 < sqrt(Value1)

Strategy 3:
Notify when Sum of Value1, Value2, ValueN > 1000

Strategy 4:
Notify when Total := Value1 * 2 + 3^ValueN < 1234
```

I'd rather not let users write custom JS code for security and usability reasons if there's a better way.

Using a predefined html form would not allow for a lot of flexibility without being extremely complex.

Is there already a technique or framework to solve this kind of problem I'm not aware of?

Comment: what flexibility you want? not really seems flexible in you strategy example.

Comment: @appleapple Should allow the usage of multiple columns and calculations involving multiple columns. Added more relevant strategies

Comment: I'd recommend custom js code for this, if it is all executed in custom's browser and never went to server, there are no security concern.

Comment: or you can define your own script language, but I don't think it's anyway easier for users.

Comment: even if it went to server (something like sync between devices), it's still safe if not executed (by server or by other user)

Comment: @appleapple There may be some security concerns if a user can execute arbitrary js code on their account and then somehow force other user to log into the attackers account causing such code to be executed. Proper sanitization would not be unnecessary even if the code is not shared across accounts.

Comment: build a simple custom query language. Or you can directly execute commands from users using `eval()` **BUT** its **not secure**...

Comment: @shardl fair point. but if the attacker can do so, I think the victim have **already** under the risk of execute any script.... Just like if someone use other's computer, anything can happens.